# I need to count bangla and english letters from a text-area

Tags: javascript, unicode, charactercount, bangla-font

I'm counting character using `something.length` of java script function. For bangla character it counts wrongly. Like what online character counter counts 325 it counts 313.For example:

> "#NAME#কে সিলেক্ট করার জন্য ধন্যবাদ। প্রেসক্রিপশনটি ফোনে পেতে "যত্ন" এপ ডাউনলোড করুন: rebrand.ly/zn5im2k  আপনি ঠিক টাইম এ চলে আসবেন। ডাক্তার আপনার জন্য অপেক্ষা করবে। ঠিক টাইম এ না আসলে আপনার টাকা লস হবে। পরে আমাদের কিছু বলতে পারবেন না। পুরোটাই আপানার দায়িত্ব হবে। আমাদের জানান দরকার আমরা আপনার সাথে যোগাযোগ করব রাত"

for unicode character count it is 238. I just what to know, is there any way i can count the unicode character the way unicode character counts in javascripts

Comment: What is the correct character count?

Comment: for unicode charecter count it should be 238. i just what to know, is there any way i can count the unicode character the way unicode character counts in javascripts.